# error "no module named bs4"

Tags: python-2.7

"ImportError: No module named bs4" this error comes every time i run the code. even trying "pip install beautifulSoup4" does not solve the problem.by the way pip does work by itself.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = raw_input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")

r = requests.get("http://"+url)
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

When I try to install beautifulsoup, it hangs after this command:

[image]

Comment: Please insert code instead of screens (easier to read)

Comment: What do you mean by pip "doesn't run"? Does it hang? does it produce an error?

Comment: what is the error you receive?

Comment: Does `pip` by itself work? Have you tried `pip --version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your current version of pip using `pip -V`
If you are not using latest version, upgrade your pip.

Before installing try `pip search <Package Name>`

Better to install anaconda, no need to install all the libraries manually as they already come with anaconda.
Here's the link: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: the pip version it shows pip 8.0.2. What next? The command pip search <package name> shows syntax error. And what is this anaconda for?

Comment: Your pip version is the latest available.


Anaconda is a completely free Python distribution. As you know python by default does not provide all the libraries. By installing anaconda, about 400 most important libraries are installed.

Comment: Try to reinstall pip. Add the error message in the question(do not add its screenshot, copy-paste the error). 
Anaconda also provides bs4, so it can solve your problem. About your error I can't say anything about it without seeing the error message.

Comment: I installed Anaconda, python 27 and Anaconda are two different folders in C:\\ drive. is it ohkay to have them in different folders ? i still found the error "ImportError: No module named bs4" on running the code

Comment: Did you installed anaconda for python2 or python3?
They are supposed to be in two different folders, it is no problem.

Comment: Download the anaconda for the same version as of your python, otherwise it won't work. 

Word of advice: If you are using python2 switch to python3, work on the latest. Get yourself comfortable with python3.

Comment: i installed for python2. Is there a way to upgrade to python3 OR i will have to uninstall and get python3 installed again?

Comment: You can have both python2 and python3, but i would recommend uninstalling python2 and then installing 3, having both sometimes create problem. After that, install anaconda for python 3. This will work.
If still the problem continues let me know.

Comment: If you are CS major, switch to linux ASAP, windows is not good for developers, Linux is open source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    pip install beautifulsoup4